# NAudio - Stop WaveOut playback

Tags: c#, winforms, naudio

I am using Naudio for a winform project, when the first form loads it basically 
call another form and initialize a WaveOut object passing the form handle to the constructor.

```
//in form 1
{
   Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
   frm2.InitializeWaveOut(this.Handle);
   frm2.Show();
} 

//in form 2
public void InitializeWaveOut(IntPtr wHandle)
{
  WaveOut wo = new WaveOut(wHandle);
  wo.DeviceNumber = 0;

  // etc...
}

Form2_Load()
{
  wo.Play();
}
```

All is working, and the sounds are played correctly, but i need to be able to click a button to stop (pause) the audio for a limited time and then resume it. Once again this is working correctly but only if i load one instance of form2, as soon as I load a second instance of it and try to stop the audio on the **first** created instance of form2, it hangs, while the second one keeps functioning. I need a way to stop the audio on a form without hanging the other, on the same devicenumber.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass a handle into `WaveOut` - the default constructor will create a separate handle for each instance, so their messages don't get muddled up.